# Перезагрузка и редирект на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Как можно осуществить перезагрузку и редирект с таймером?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждые пять секунд будет происходить перезагрузка страницы:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.location.href = document.location;
},5000);
```

Для редиректа - указываем адрес:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.location.href = 'http://hashcode.ru/';
},5000);
```

Comment: недостаточно jQuery!

>Каждые пять секунд

что-то напутали